# Ruby Hash Value into Array of Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have a hash {:a => b} and I want to add a value to that key and turn it into an array of values keeping the previous one.

So the result would be {:a => [b, c]}

Is there a better way to do this than iterating through the hash?

Comment: No :-) You have to iterate anyway, so what is your question? "What is the shortest way to reach ..."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This.

```
h = {a: b}
h[:a] = ((a[:a].is_a? Array) ? a[:a] : [a[:a]]) << c
```

Comment: The original question doesn't mention whether `b` might possibly already be an array.  If that's possible, you may want add a check.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to create a Hash of Arrays:

```
h = {}
h[:a] = []
h[:a].push(b)
h[:a].push(c)
```

What I mean: Even if there's only one value use an array. That makes handling easier.